# How to use the DELETE request in Dispatch for Scala?

Tags: scala, http, get, httprequest, scala-dispatch

I what to do is to make a `DELETE` request using [dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html). I know how to use it in `POST` and `GET`, but it seems that I can't find samples on how to use `DELETE`?

Answer (score 1):

```
:/("www.scala-lang.org").DELETE
```

where `:/` constructs new request. Some code snippets are available [here](https://github.com/ssuravarapu/Terrastore-Scala-Client/blob/master/src/main/scala/terrastore/client/TerrastoreClient.scala), just to help you get started.